# Create a weak reference to an object

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection, weak-references

Is it possible in Actionscript 3 to create a weak reference to an object, so that it can be garbage collected.

I'm creating some classes to make debugging easier, so I don't want the objects to hang around in memory if they are only referenced here (and of course I don't want to fill the code with callbacks to remove the objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grant Skinner has written an excellent series of articles on [resource management in ActionScript 3](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html), and in the third part of that series he introduces [the WeakReference and the WeakProxyReference](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html) helper classes that can be used for this.

Answer (score 3):

Right now I've made a simple class to  take advantage of the Dictionary weakKeys parameter:

```
public class WeakReference
{
    private var dic

    public function WeakReference(object)
    {
        this.dic = new Dictionary(true)
        this.dic[object] = true
    }

    public function get Value()
    {
        for (var object in this.dic)
        {
            return object
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: @mattlohkamp Semi-colons aren't necessary sometimes, but it's a good pratice to use them. This applies to entire ECMAScript, they're empty statements, while commas make sequence expressions. E.g: `trace(1), trace(2);`. it works in both JS and AS3 (except that the global JS object doesn't have a getter/setter/property for `trace`).